# Suppress `Expected an identifier and instead saw 'default' (a reserved word)` in JSLint with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jslint, jshint

I'm using `jshint` to validate my JavaScript files.

On the server-side I'm using node.js with Mongoose. In Mongoose I'm encouraged to write schemata in a fashion like:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname : { type: String, default: '' }
});
```

When running linting, I get error:

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw 'default' (a reserved word).
```

Is there a way to suppress this error? I really would prefer that behaviour instead of writing:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname : { type: String, "default": '' }
});
```

Comment: Technically speaking, that is invalid JS, although most environments seem to allow it. I'm not sure if there is a configuration option in JSHint though.

Comment: I really get the point in that. Why does Mongoose suggest us to write invalid JS? :/

Comment: Just put it in quotes and move on.  It bugged me at first too, but now I feel like a dope for even spending time thinking about it.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I share that feeling right now. Moving on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the "es5" option to disable this from occurring.

See: http://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-identifier-and-instead-saw-a-a-reserved-word/

Comment: Works as well for "Expected an identifier and instead saw 'finally' (a reserved word)." which is an issue when using AngularJS's Promise API.

Comment: If you're still seeing this error then you should update your version of JSHint. Since 2.0.0 the `es5` option has been enabled by default but I'm still seeing loads of referrals to the linked article from this answer.

Answer (score 5):

`default` is indeed a reserved word in JavaScript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). While technically you can use default in an object property name without any problems, you could end up having problems with that notation if your interpreter is strict (like lint is).

Simplest way to go forward: fix the problem by adding quotes. Lint won't whine you any longer. The code is two characters longer, but so what - linting passes and you are guaranteed to not have problems due to use of a reserved keyword.