# will exports['delete'] run as exports.delete in nodejs

Tags: node.js

as [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936180/suppress-expected-an-identifier-and-instead-saw-default-a-reserved-word-in), I assumed that if I write `exports['delete']`, it will run as `exports.delete` in nodejs.

assumed that I have this chunked code,

```
exports['delete'] =
function(params) {

  var authCookie =
  this
  .server
  .authCookie
  .apply(
    ini,
    [
      params
    ]
  );
```

Will it runs as

```
exports.delete =
function(params) {

  var authCookie =
  this
  .server
  .authCookie
  .apply(
    ini,
    [
      params
    ]
  );
```

Then I can called it from outside??

Answer (score 0):

not only in this case, as far as your parameter is a valid javascript identifier those two are the same,
for example:

```
object.name
```

is exactly the same as:

```
object['name']
```

if `name` isn't a valid identifier you shall use the second form, 
and remember the first form is encouraged.

Comment: You'll need to use the `object['name']` form if `name` isn't a valid JavaScript identifier (e.g. `object['2delete']`).